# How to change it to show minutes instead of seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change my display so instead of calculating seconds it calculates the minutes because when I tried to do the remminuts it did not work and im not quite sure where i am going wrong.

Here is the code for the javascript:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.counter');
const buttonsDiv = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const secInput = document.getElementById('seconds');

var seconds;
var remseconds;
var minuts;
var toCount = false;

function toSubmit(){
    display('start');
    remove('seconds');
    remove('ok');
    seconds = Number(secInput.value);
    counting();
}

function display(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block';
}

function remove(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
}

function check(stat){
    if(stat.id == "start"){
        display("stop");
        remove("start");
        toCount = true;
    }
    else if(stat.id == "stop"){
        display("continue");
        remove("stop");
        toCount = false
    }
    else{
        display("stop");
        remove("continue");
        toCount =true;
    }
}

function count(){
    if(seconds > 0){
        if(toCount == true){
            seconds--;
            remseconds = seconds % 60;
            minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

            if(minuts < 10){
                minuts = "0" + minuts;
            }

            if(remseconds < 10){
                remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
            }

            container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
        }
    }
    else{
        container.innerHTML = "DONE!";
        buttonsDiv.style.opacity = "0";
    }
}

function counting(){
    remseconds = seconds % 60;
    minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);


    if(remseconds < 10){
        remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
    }

    container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
    setInterval(count, 1000);
}
```

As you can see it's calculating for the seconds, but when I tried minutes instead, I got no results from it so i am very stuck on what i might be doing wrong.

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] in a snippet, or at least an example of current output and desired output? I didn't understand what is your issue right now

Comment: You also defined 'minuts'

Comment: What should i change it too?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about accuracy you can use a function like this:

`const secs = x => Math.round(x/60)`

This however calculates 0 (mins) when you enter 29 (seconds). If you don't like that search for a more sophisticated solution online.

Comment: But i want the user to input minutes not the seconds.

Comment: Well then just multiply the user input value by 60. If this is out of your reach you should visit w3schools and understand the basics